# What is "Override Resource in Other Configuration"?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio sometimes suggest me to "Override Resource in Other Configuration". What does it do exactly? Why Android Studio is asking me this, am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you're not doing something wrong. It is only recommending that you provide [additional resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (locale, resolution, orientation).